# Invocable method icon not visible

Tags: slds, invocable-method

I defined an invocable method with an SLDS icon like this:

```
@InvocableMethod(Label='Clone Opportunity' IconName='slds:action:clone')
```

Today I noticed that the SLDS icon is not displayed in the Flow Builder. Auto-Layout is active.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And I also just noticed that I do not see the description anywhere. Maybe it's a similar issue?

Comment: I have a feeling that the InvocableMethod annotations are actually case sensitive, so you should be using label and iconName as per the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm)

Comment: In the past, the docs really didn't care about case sensitivity - so I don't really trust the documentation at all. Especially annotations were not very consistent, and in Camel Case, rather than Pascal Case. But the idea is pretty good and I tried it - but to no avail. It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I always used those modifiers in camelCase and they worked, e.g. `iconName='slds:standard:email' label='Something' category='SomethingElse'`.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) you could use a `slds:standard` icons or a SVG uploaded as a static resource:

> The name of the icon to use as a custom icon for the action in the Flow Builder canvas. You can specify an SVG file that you uploaded as a static resource or a Salesforce Lightning Design System **standard icon**.

To quickly test it, you could try changing the iconName to a standard one:

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Clone Opportunity' iconName='slds:standard:email')
```

So you could [download SLDS icons](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/assets/downloads/salesforce-lightning-design-system-icons.zip) and upload the needed one as static resource.

Comment: Interesting - I never read that part. Either way - I copied your exact example and it's still not working. I might try adding them as a static resource and see what happens.

Comment: @Semmel That's odd, I tested it again right before posting this answer: for me it worked using a standard icon while it didn't work using an action one. Please note that it takes few seconds to display the right icon for the apex action if it's already in the flow, so what happens is that the apex action is loaded with the default icon, then after a while (~10s in the previous test, but there isn't a min/max) the right one will be shown.